# Is WebMatrix a good replacement for Coda on Windows?

Tags: ide, coda, webmatrix

Like some other posters I'm quite happy with Coda on Mac, but looking for a strong equivalent for Windows.

Microsoft recently released a new tool called WebMatrix, which looks promising.  I'm nervous about trying a 1.0 release of a Microsoft IDE.  I know a lot of people recommend Aptana, but really dislike (I don't know why) it's Eclipse-based feel.

Any feedback on this new tool?  How's it's parity with Coda?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's a 15 MB download (assuming you have .NET 4.0 installed). I have been playing with WebMatrix since its first beta. There is nothing to be "nervous" about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coda doesn't have a built in database manager - WebMatrix includes a management module for SQLCE databases.  You can create tables, relationships, indices etc, as well as work with data.

Aside from that, they're pretty much the same idea.  WebMatrix looks to have slightly better publishing power (haven't played with the publish stuff too much yet).

I've played with WebMatrix to see what it is like.  I'll stick with Visual Studio, but for web site's rather than applications, it could be quite good.

Comment: Thank You!  I'd Give you an "up vote" but I don't have the reputation for it yet.

Comment: Just as a very belated follow-up, I've moved to ST3. Now that I'm more experienced, its power is amazing.